# Oracle:Select Statement with If else in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have following two tables TestCustomer and TestEmail.I would like to retrieve emailAddress based on email_stat on  TestCustomer and outside boolean parameter "noFlag".If noFlag is "true" get all the email addresses associated with customer_id other get only "A" ones.Any Help would be appreciated.

```
create table TestEmail(emai_id varchar(18),emailaddress varchar(20))

create table TestCustomer(customer_id varchar(18),emai_id varchar(18),email_stat char(1))

Insert Into TestEmail(emai_id,emailaddress)values('12345','abc@gmail.com');
Insert Into TestEmail(emai_id,emailaddress)values('123456','abcd@gmail.com');
Insert Into TestEmail(emai_id,emailaddress)values('123457','abcde@gmail.com');

Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223459','12345','A');
Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223458','123456','I');
Insert Into TestCustomer(customer_id,emai_id,email_stat)values('223459','123457','A');
```

**Expected Input:**

customer_id=223458 and noFlag='true'

**Expected Output**
[image]

**Expected Input:**

customer_id=223458 and noFlag='false'

**Expected Output**

Empty Result.

Comment: why is this tagged mysql?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT [DISTINCT] emailaddress 
FROM TestEmail
JOIN TestCustomer USING (emai_id)
-- insert parameter-1 instead of 223458
WHERE TestCustomer.customer_id = 223458                      
-- insert parameter-2 instead of 'noFlag'
  AND TestCustomer.email_stat = CASE WHEN noFlag = 'true' 
                                     THEN TestCustomer.email_stat
                                     ELSE 'A'
                                     END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07717459aef6baa03ce6376b60a450b4)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the emails, you can use `exists`:

```
select e.emailaddress
from testemail e
where exists (select 1
              from testcustomer c
              where c.email_id = e.email_id and
                    c.customer_id = :customer_id and
                    (c.email_stat = 'A' or :noflag = 'true')
             );
```

Comment: how to modify this if i want some fields from TestCustomer too

Comment: That is not the question that you asks here.  This answers the question you have asked.